# How to Search for Multiple Terms in Excel and Return a Phrase?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to check if a term is present in one cell, and then return a value if that term is present.
For example, in the cell A1, the phrase "marriott marquis houston" is present, I want, if the word "marquis" is present, for there to be an output in cell B1 saying "marquis".  I want to check for several terms so this should be respeatable

=IF(SEARCH("jw",E258)," jw marriott",
IF(SEARCH("westin",E258)," Westin"))

etc, but it didn't work

I tried using =XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet3!A:A,E30)),Sheet3!B:B,"")

with the table below, but I'm getting #NAME?
[Reference Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ETJ1.png)

Comment: use a lookup table and reference that with INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP if you have it.

Comment: The lookup info isn't uniform- it is the full name of the hotel like "the westin atlanta airport"

Answer (score 0):

Put your lookup and wanted outputs in a table and use XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G1:G2,A1)),H1:H2,"")
```

[image]

---

If one does not have XLOOKUP then INDEX/AGGREGATE will work:

```
=INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(G1:G2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G1:G2,A1))),1))
```

[image]

---

One note on these.  this will return `Westin` if `Westing` is found in the text string, it does not look at whole words.

If that is desired, change the SEARCH to include spaces:

```
SEARCH(" "&G1:G2&" "," "&A1&" ")
```

Though note that if there is punctuation, that may need to dealt with also.

Comment: The lookup info isn't uniform- it is the full name of the hotel like "the westin atlanta airport"

Comment: The lookup is the part you are putting in your search.  It does not matter what is in the string.  IF you put `the westin atlanta airport` in `A1` which would be your `E258` my `B2` would return `Westin` as your attempt wanted.

Comment: Ok I tried =XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet3!A:A,E2)),Sheet3!B:B,"")---do you see any issues

Comment: I'm uploading an image of the sheet 3 reference tables

Comment: Beside doing full columns (in this type, one should limit the ranges) I do not see anything wrong.  What error do you get?

Comment: If you get `#NAME` you do not have `XLOOKUP` you need to go with the INDEX/AGGREGATE version. `=INDEX(Sheet3!B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Sheet3!A1:A1000)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet3!A1:A1000,A1))),1))`